# Create Word Document in C++

Tags: c++, windows, com

I am new to COM programming in C++ and while this code works welcome suggestions to improve readability/reliability. This creates a blank word document and adds the text Hello, World.

```
// The Microsoft Office Object type library (mso.dll)
    #import "libid:2DF8D04C-5BFA-101B-BDE5-00AA0044DE52" raw_interfaces_only, named_guids,\
        rename("DocumentProperties", "_DocumentProperties"), \
        rename("SearchPath", "_SearchPath"), \
        rename("RGB", "_RGB")

     //  The Microsoft Office Word Object type library (msword.olb)
    #import "libid:00020905-0000-0000-C000-000000000046" raw_interfaces_only,\
        rename("ExitWindows", "_ExitWindows"), \
        rename("ReplaceText", "_ReplaceText"), \
        rename("FindText", "_FindText"), \
        rename("RGB", "_RGB")
    #include <Windows.h>

    int main()
    {
        HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
        Word::_ApplicationPtr pWordApp;
        Word::DocumentsPtr pWordDocs;
        Word::_DocumentPtr pWordDoc;
        Word::RangePtr pRange;
        hr = pWordApp.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Word::Application));
        pWordApp->put_Visible(VARIANT_TRUE);
        pWordApp->get_Documents(&pWordDocs);

        pWordDoc.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Word::Document));
        pRange.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Word::Range));
        VARIANT vTemplate;
        VariantInit(&vTemplate);
        vTemplate.vt = VT_BSTR;
        vTemplate.bstrVal = SysAllocString(L"");

        VARIANT vNewTemplate;
        VariantInit(&vNewTemplate);
        vNewTemplate.vt = VT_BOOL;
        vNewTemplate.boolVal = false;

        VARIANT vDocType;
        VariantInit(&vDocType);
        vDocType.vt = VT_I4;
        vDocType.iVal = Word::WdNewDocumentType::wdNewBlankDocument;

        VARIANT vVisible;
        VariantInit(&vVisible);
        vVisible.vt = VT_BOOL;
        vVisible.boolVal = true;

        VARIANT vStart;
        VariantInit(&vStart);
        vStart.vt = VT_I4;
        vStart.iVal = 0;

        VARIANT vEnd;
        VariantInit(&vEnd);
        vEnd.vt = VT_I4;
        vEnd.iVal = 0;

        pWordDocs->Add(&vTemplate, &vNewTemplate, &vDocType, &vVisible, &pWordDoc);
        pWordDoc->Range(&vStart, &vEnd, &pRange);

        BSTR str = SysAllocString(L"Hello, World!");
        pRange->put_Text(str);
        SysFreeString(str); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, I think it's worth thinking carefully about whether C++ is the best tool for this task.  It certainly can be done, but you may find better documentation/more support for COM/interop from C# or VBA.  Particularly for such a simple task.

---

```
HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
```

You need to check the result of `CoInitializeEx` and every other API call you make.  Think of each API call as a polite request.  Windows may (and frequently does) decline requests.  In your program, these errors will be really hard to diagnose because you will simply not see your desired result.  A better idea is to use a function/macro to check the result is correct.  In this case, it should look something like:

```
assert(S_OK == CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED));
```

You may want to get fancier with the macro.  This way you will know where (and where not) to spend time debugging.

---

Quoting [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-coinitializeex):

> To close the COM library gracefully on a thread, each successful call to CoInitialize or CoInitializeEx, including any call that returns S_FALSE, must be balanced by a corresponding call to CoUninitialize.

You forgot to call `CoUninitialize`.  Your program (well, actually your thread) is supposed to tell Windows when it will start using COM and when it is done.

This is a great place to use RAII:

```
struct COMThread {
    COMThread() {
        assert(S_OK == CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED));
    }

    ~ COMThread() {
        CoUninitialize(); // returns void, no need to check return value
    }
};
```

In general you should read MSDN for every function you call and probably write a few comments summarizing your findings (and maybe even a URL... sometimes the docs are hard to re-find IMO).

---

```
vTemplate.bstrVal = SysAllocString(L"")
```

Did you forget to deallocate this BSTR?  This could be another RAII wrapper.

---

```
VARIANT vTemplate;
VariantInit(&vTemplate);
vTemplate.vt = VT_BSTR;
```

Once again, there is a `free` function [`VariantClear`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-variantclear) which could be RAII.  A wrapper around variant is not a bad idea -- most of your code creates/clears variants.

---

I could not find docs for the specific Word functions you are calling, but I suspect there is a way to achieve this without using so many variants (based on some experience using other parts of the COM API).  I know this is not as helpful as it could be.

---

Despite a few things to clean up, I think you're off to a good start.  You have the general procedure down which is the most important thing.